# Abrir archivo PDF JCIFS Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy intentado abrir un pdf en mi aplicación android, el archivo lo tengo en un servidor, mediante SmbFile consigo llegar hasta el archivo pero no soy capaz de abrirlo ni con Intent ni con  SmbFileInputStream. Sabéis donde puedo encontrar información o como abrirlo?????

Debería descargarlo y luego abrirlo???

Muchas gracias y saludos

---

El codigo que tengo es este

```
   try {

                String user = "xxxx";
                String pass = "xxxx";
                String url = "smb:" + enlace;
                NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(
                        "xxxxx", user, pass);
                SmbFile sfile = new SmbFile(url, auth);
                SmbFileInputStream in = new SmbFileInputStream(sfile);
```

La variable enlace la obtengo de una consulta que me da el enlace exacto a un archivo pdf (antes de este codigo) pero no soy capaz de abrirlo :(

Comment: Agrega más información, que permisos tienes definidos ? que se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: @Elenasys buenas, ahora no tengo acceso al código hasta mañana, lo que necesito es abrir el pdf ya que si hago un if  a sfile.isFile es true y si le saco los datos en el log saca cientos de caracteres, lo que no se es abrirlo. mil gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

He intentado descargar el archivo a la carpeta cache para abrir el archivo desde alli pero tampoco consigo abrirlo, mi código es este.

En una consulta obtengo la url y la monto correctamente para samba.

```
 enlace = (rs.getString("IDENTHIJO"));
 enlace= enlace.replace("\\", "/");
 enlace = enlace.replaceAll("FICHEROS", "192.168.10.12");
```

compruebo que el archivo samba existe y si existe, lo copio a la carpeta cache.
Si existe en la carpeta cache lanzo el metodo mostrarPDF.

```
 try {

                String user = "xxxxx";
                String pass = "xxxxx";
                String url = "smb:" + enlace;
                NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(
                        "xxxxxxx", user, pass);
                SmbFile sfile = new SmbFile(url, auth);
                if (sfile.exists()) {
                    File destination = new File(getCacheDir(), "plano.pdf");
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    Uri path = Uri.parse(destination.toString());
                    InputStream in = sfile.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);

                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buf, 0, len);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                    if (destination.exists()) {
                        mostrarPDF(path, ComprobarAlmacen.this);
                        destination.delete();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ComprobarAlmacen.this, "NO EXISTE EL ARCHIVO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(ComprobarAlmacen.this, "No he llegado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Y el metodo para abrir el PDF

```
public void mostrarPDF(Uri nombPdf, Context context) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Visualizando documento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(nombPdf, "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No existe una aplicación para abrir el PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

El log me muestra lo siguiente

```
2020-09-16 17:17:44.943 2635-2700/com.example.errece D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdd505480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdd503770)
```

2020-09-16 17:17:52.603 2635-2635/com.example.errece I/Choreographer: Skipped 455 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-09-16 17:17:52.610 2635-2700/com.example.errece I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=7600ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=86432318701565, Vsync=86439902034595, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=86439912154900, AnimationStart=86439912207700, PerformTraversalsStart=86439912382700, DrawStart=86439912513600, SyncQueued=86439913529800, SyncStart=86439913642800, IssueDrawCommandsStart=86439913721300, SwapBuffers=86439914151700, FrameCompleted=86439919075000, DequeueBufferDuration=68000, QueueBufferDuration=2491000,
2020-09-16 17:17:52.710 2635-2700/com.example.errece D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdd505480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdd503770)
2020-09-16 17:17:52.733 2635-2700/com.example.errece D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdd505480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdd503770)
2020-09-16 17:17:52.928 2635-2700/com.example.errece D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdd505480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdd503770)
2020-09-16 17:17:52.932 2635-2700/com.example.errece D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdd505480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdd503770)

No se como tengo que hacerlo!!!!
muchas gracias!!!!